# Sum and average values of multiple objects in an array into one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, object

I have an array with multiple objects. I want to get the average and sum of their values.

Example original array:

```
[[{count: 2}],[{count: 10}]]
```

Final array:

```
Sum array: [{count: 12}]
Average array: [{count: 6}]
```

I tried using reduce... but it doesn't work if I have multiple keys in the array as it returns one number only.

Any idea how I would approach this?

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    let average = arr[i].reduce((a, b) => a + b) / arr.length;
    console.log(average)
}
```

Comment: Instead of  directly asking for answer, show your research.. what all you have tried ( the code ) using loops and reduce..

Comment: You missed the point that accumulator can hold objects as well. What ever you return from your function is the accumulators value. So if you return an object like `{sum: [{count: 12}], avg: [{count: 6}]}` it will be your accumulator. You can do pretty complex things with this. Also it takes an additional parameter after the callback function which will be used as the initial value so you can defenitely handle multiple keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but here is an example of accumulating multiple keys into a new object using `reduce()`. It also tracks the total number of each key encountered in case not all objects in the array have the same keys. The format you want your result array in is unclear, but I've shown an example of calculating the averages from the result of the `reduce()` call.

```js
const arr = [
  {count1: 3, count2: 2}, 
  {count1: 4, count2: 10},
  {count1: 3, count3: 2}
  ];

const sumObj = arr.reduce((a, o) => (
  Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => (
    a[k] = {...a[k] ?? {sum: 0, total: 0}}
    , a[k]['sum'] += v
    , a[k]['total'] += 1)
    ), a), {});

console.log(sumObj);

const averageArr = Object.entries(sumObj).map(([k, {sum, total}]) => ({key: k, average: sum/total}));

console.log(averageArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map and reduce like so given multiple keys:

```
const exampleArray = [{swag: 3, count: 2}, {swag: 4, count: 10}];

// converting into array with only the key you want to use
const countArray = exampleArray.map((element) => element.count); // an array with just {count: value} elements in them.

// ... now reduce like normally
```

Comment: would this work if I have multiple keys to reduce from? I don't need the map... I need to reduce multiple keys

Comment: How are you referring to multiple keys? As in multiple instances of a count or multiple actual keys like my example?

Comment: multiple actual keys and I want to sum each key individually into the same array

Comment: can you give a better example for your use case here?